# What does the || operator do?

Tags: javascript, operators

```
Attacklab.wmd_env.buttons=Attacklab.wmd_env.buttons||_4;
```

what does the || do in this case?
Adds _4 to the array which is Attacklab.wmd_env.buttons?

Comment: Wow it took 7 attempts to get the title right...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21367903/javascript-false-undefined-vs-undefined-false

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `||` operator in JavaScript returns the value on the left if that value does not evaluate to `false`, otherwise it returns the value on the right.

From [Mozilla's Core JavaScript 1.5 Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators):

> `expr1 || expr2`
>   Returns `expr1` if it can be converted to true; otherwise, returns `expr2`. Thus, when used with Boolean values, `||` returns true if either operand is true; if both are false, returns false.

So, in this case, if `Attacklab.wmd_env.buttons` doesn't have a value, it sets the value to `_4`.

Comment: It's strange that MDC uses rather ambiguous "Returns expr1 if it **can be converted** to true". It's not really about "able to be converted", it's about which value expression returns.

Answer (score 12):

It's a fancy way of writing

```
if(!Attacklab.wmd_env.buttons)
    Attacklab.wmd_env.buttons = _4;
```

It's nice for providing default values. Keep in mind that not only `null` and `undefined` will trigger the conditional, but also `0`, `false` and `''`, ie everything which is considered `false` in boolean contexts.

Comment: @kangax: yup, that was the only thing missing in the list (see ECMA-262, section 9.2)

Answer (score 8):

If `Attacklab.wmd_env.buttons` is `null` or `undefined`, it will be set to the default value `_4`.

Answer (score 4):

The || operator checks whether the value provided on the left side of the expression is false (in a boolean context). If so it returns an alternate value indicated by the right side of the expression. Otherwise it returns the original value.

So for example the following code would set 'Foo' to a default value if it is null:

```
Foo = Foo || "Default Value"
```

This is sometimes called the Coalescing operator. 
It is supported in other languages such as Ruby and Perl. C# has the ?? operator which does the same thing.

Comment: So, with this answer he knows what it's called, and what other langagues use it, and even the different syntax in C#...and he still doesn't know what it does.

Comment: Good point, I probably should have just left a comment. Anyway, my answer has been updated.

Comment: +1 for the correct name! No other SO questions/answers seemed to want to give that... Helped me find the equivalent in Xquery (it's let $foo := ($foo, "default value")[1] for anyone who's curious).