# javascript: is this a conditional assignment?

Tags: javascript

From the google analytics tracking code:

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
```

how does this work?

Is it a conditional variable value assignment?
Is it the same as saying:

```
if( !(_gaq) ) {_gaq = []; }
```

?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the || operator do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/830618/what-does-the-operator-do)

Comment: Short answer: yes (although the second one creates a global `_gaq` *edit:* if we assume that `_gaq` does not exist).

Comment: @Felix — unless something else applies a different scope to `_gaq`

Comment: I would add that given the specifics of this questions, those two statements also differ in that you cannot use the syntax of the former to conditionally define a global variable as it will throw a reference error.

Comment: Also worth noting is that if you had purposely set `_gaq` to a falsy value (like `0`), then it would be reassigned the value of `[]`. So it doesn't behave exactly like conditional assignment in Ruby.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The or operator (`||`) will return the left hand side if it is a true value, otherwise it will return the right hand side.

It is very similar to your second example, but since it makes use of the `var` keyword, it also establishes a local scope for the variable.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is.

The `||` operator evaluates to its leftmost "truthy" operand.
If `_gaq` is "falsy" (such as `null`, `undefined`, or `0`), it will evaluate to the right side (`[]`).

Comment: or `false` or `""` (empty string)

Answer (score 2):

It's the same as saying:

```
if( !(_gaq) ) {var _gaq = [];}
```

(This can be done since the var is hoisted above the conditional check, thereby avoiding a 'not defined' error, and it will also cause _gaq to be automatically treated as local in scope.)

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's **not** the same as saying:

```
if (!_gaq) _gaq = [];
```

at least not necessarily.  Consider this:

```
function outer() {
  var _gaq = null;
  function inner() {
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    // ...
  }

  inner();
  _gaq = 1;
  inner();
}
```

When there's a "_gaq" (I hate typing that, by the way) in an outer lexical scope, what you end up with is a **new** variable in the inner scope.  The "if" statement differs in that very important way — there would only be one "_gaq" in that case.