# Using a try catch around an object literal

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Inside a callback I build an object I build to send out in my Express app:

```
this.response = {
      owner: data.actions[1].causes[0].shortDescription,
      build_version: data.actions[0].parameters[0].value,
      branch_to_merge: data.actions[0].parameters[1].value,
      jira_tickets: data.actions[0].parameters[2].value,
      build_description: data.actions[0].parameters[3].value,
      outcome: data.result
    };
```

If I get a different response than what I'm used to I get a fatal `cannot find 'property' of undefined` error that crashes my server caused by these: `data.actions[1].causes[0].shortDescription`.

I was wondering what to do about it and I thought I could just put it in a `try catch` but that seems wrong.

What's considered a good way of dealing with this?

Comment: [short circuiting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-Circuit_Evaluation) could help, but would be rather messy with how deeply nested your properties are.

Comment: `if-else` statements? :) Good way is to handle different scenarios and construct proper data based on that. If you don't know what's going on, then it's not good.

Comment: Accessing nested data in this way is like defusing bomb, you never know when it explodes. I would suggest libraries that add the checking the path your accessing, O.get("data.actions.1.causes.0") https://github.com/mariocasciaro/object-path, also the lodash, ramda has methods to access nested data safely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### 1. use try/catch

In your statement you have:

- 26 potential sources for Reference errors (16 missing objects, 10 array out of bounds).

**That's what try/catch handles best.** Dealing with the same type of error from a block of code and handling in one place. So unless you want to deal with each potential error individually, try/catch is the simplest and best tool you at your disposal. It works and you can pinpoint the problem:

```
var w = {}
try {w.x.y.z} catch(e) {e}
```

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'y' of undefined(…)

Alternatively, if you need more control, you could

#### 2. test all references up-front

If it must succeed even if some properties fail, you can check each reference. e.g.:

```
var sdValid = data && 
            data.actions && 
            data.actions.length>1 && 
            data.actions[0].causes && 
            data.actions[0].causes.length && 
            data.actions[1].causes[0].shortDescription;
var owner = sdValid
            ?  data.actions[1].causes[0].shortDescription 
            : 'default value';
this.response = {
    owner : owner,
    // etc... 
}
```

You can easily make it more readable if you

#### 3. roll out your own reference checker

```
this.response = {
    owner : nestget(data, 'nobody')
               .prop('actions', 1)
               .prop('causes', 0)
               .prop('shortDescription')
               .value(), 
               // return shortDescription if you got this far or 'nobody'

    build_version : nestget(data, '0.0.0')
               .prop('actions', 0)
               .prop('parameters', 0)
               .prop('value')
               .value(),
               // return value if you got this far or '0.0.0'
    // ... etc
};

// Custom - easy to use reference checker
function nestget (obj, default) {
   var valid = false;
   this.default = default;
   this.obj = obj;
   var that = this;

   return { 
       prop : propChecker,
       value : getValue
   }

   function propChecker (prop, i) {
      // implementation omitted for brevity
   }
   function getValue () {
      return value;
   }
}
```

#### 4. use a library

Last but not least, you can always use a library. Personally I like how XPath searches XML trees so I would suggest using something like [JSONPath](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) to search for nested objects in a data structure. e.g.

```
this.response = {
    owner : jsonpath(data, '$..shortDescription[0]'),
    build_version jsonpath(data, '$.actions[0].parameters[0].value'), // no error
    // ... etc
}
```

However, there are lots of options out there (e.g. lodash/underscore as mentioned in a comment).

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    //unwrap your data
}
catch(err) {
    //handle the failure
}
```

is a good solution, depending on how nuanced you want to be

If you want to continue with execution even if one or more is failed, you might consider the conditional assignment operator

[javascript: is this a conditional assignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167883/javascript-is-this-a-conditional-assignment).

```
this.response = {
      owner: data.actions[1].causes[0].shortDescription || undefined,
      etc: data.something || undefined
    };
```

Of course, you will have to make sure the stuff that handles this.response upstream is not going to blow up for the same reason.

Edit: The above is not working for me, though I thought it was a feature of javascript. If you can't get it to work, you can accomplish the same thing with the ternary operator

```
var asdf = (jkl == undefined) ? 3 : jkl;
```

Which says

```
if(asdf == undefined) asdf = 3; else asdf = jkl
```

The trouble with this is that if you do

```
var asdf = (nested.variable == undefined) ? 3 : nested.variable;
```

Your code will break if `nested` is `undefined`. There are a few workarounds to this, such as setting a number of flags and then conditioning your ternary on those.

I've heard (and agree) that nested ternary statements is not a very good idea.

Another edit:
Check over here [How to determine if variable is 'undefined' or 'null'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647867/how-to-determine-if-variable-is-undefined-or-null) for issues regarding variables that may or may not be defined.
Apparently `== undefined` and `== null` only work if the variables are declared but not defined.
Which actually, I think that is the case for you. When in doubt though, use `typeof`.

Comment: conditional assignment won't help if any part of the nested object is undefined.

Comment: added another bit about potentially undefined variables

Comment: Looking at the problem from a different angle u could normalise the nested structure into a flatter structure and then have your usual check. There a number libraries you could use just google normalise js.