# Set value to zero after null

Tags: javascript, vue.js, autonumeric.js

I have a problem displaying a zero value after `null`.

`null` is not displayed in the input, but if I change the value to 0, it also does not appear... Maybe I'm doing something wrong? Maybe someone came across this and is there a way to fix this problem? **In the first input, I expect 0 to appear.**

```js
new Vue({
 el : '#app',
 data() {
  return {
   value : null,
   valueString: null,
  };
 },
 components: {
  VueAutonumeric,
 },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/autonumeric@4.5.7/dist/autoNumeric.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-autonumeric@1.2.6/dist/vue-autonumeric.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
 <div id="app">
  
  <p>Value is {{value}}</p><br>
  <vue-autonumeric :options="''" v-model="value"></vue-autonumeric>
  <button @click="() => value = 0">Set Zero</button>
  
  <p>ValueStrign is {{valueString}}</p><br>
  <vue-autonumeric :options="''" v-model="valueString"></vue-autonumeric>
  <button @click="() => valueString = '0'">Set '0'</button>
  
 </div>
</div>
```

*This has been fixed with a workaround by setting the value to '0'... But I think this is not good.*

Comment: Put the relevant code in the question, not some third party site.

Comment: To wit, Stack Overflow has a "snippet" feature that's basically exactly the same as a codepen but runs directly in the question. [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58270575/edit) and hit the button with an icon that looks like `<>` and you'll see. That said, what you've done is also acceptable: relevant code directly in the question and extra link outside.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fallback system

In this way you can give a default value to your variable:

```
data() {
  return {
    value : null || 0,
    valueString: null || "0",
  };
}
```

In case you don't want to change the value of your variable, do it at interpolation:

```
<p>Value is {{value || 0}}</p>
<p>ValueStrign is {{valueString || "0"}}</p>
```

More information here:
[JavaScript Variable fallback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9586278/javascript-variable-fallback)
[How to display space instead undefined and null in vue.js template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46191486/how-to-display-space-instead-undefined-and-null-in-vue-js-template)

Comment: This is of course a good solution, but sometimes I need to keep a value of zero. If set the initial construct to `null || 0`, then I can’t change this value to 0 or vice versa from 0 to null  (by the way, any other value works... wtf...)

Comment: And I also can’t keep the value `null` but show 0 - the user will be surprised because he did not set a value, but 0 is displayed