# What do two vertical lines in an object value mean in javascript?

Tags: javascript, operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the || operator do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/830618/what-does-the-operator-do)

Maybe somebody can provide a better code snippet, but what does `||` mean in the following?:

```
var time =  $(el).data('start') || new Date();
```

Is it an `or` operator and if so, how does it make sense that a variable can have two different values?

Comment: The action I hoped you'd take was to delete this question though, since it's not any different from the already asked and answered one.

Comment: I googled to find something similar to the link you mentioned but couldn't find anything using keywords like "two, double vertical line javascript". Because there wasn't much there in plain english, I decided to ask the question.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This is an `OR` operator. What you need to understand is:

- Non-boolean values are converted to a boolean when used in a logic operator.  Values that convert to `false` are called "falsy" and values that convert to `true` are called "truthy". Falsy values include things like `0`, `undefined`, `null`, and so on. See more at [Truthy and Falsy: When All is Not Equal in JavaScript](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/).
- The `OR` operator *short-circuits*: it keeps evaluating expressions until it finds on that is `true`, and then stops.

So, `var time =  $(el).data('start') || new Date();` means "set `time` to the `start` data of the `el` element, OR, if that's falsy, use the current time".

Comment: hi @apsillers, thanks for the explanation of "falsy" and "truthy". I heard those before but never knew what they meant.

Comment: Simple and straight to the point - great answer.

Answer (score 7):

```
exp1 || exp2
```

evaluates exp1. If exp1 is true then exp2 is not evaluated (known as short circuit evaluation). If exp1 returns false then exp 2 is evaluated. If exp1 OR exp2 is true then (exp1||exp2) evaluates as true.

But in Javascript, you can set values using the operator.

```
a = something

if (prop)

a = prop
```

can be rewritten as

```
a = prop || something
```

Answer (score 5):

It means 'or'. In this instance it assigns the value of `$(el).data('start')` to the variable `time` or, if that doesn't exist or instead returns `false`, it assigns instead the value returned from `new Date()`. Or, as more clearly noted by Malovolio, in comments:

> ...if `$(el).data('start')` is "falsy" (that is, undefined, null, 0, false, an empty string, or NaN), then `new Date()` is evaluated and assigned to `time`.

The important aspect of a logical operator:

> Logical operators are typically used with Boolean (logical) values; when they are, they return a Boolean value. However, the && and || operators actually return the value of one of the specified operands, so if these operators are used with non-Boolean values, they may return a non-Boolean value.

References:

- [Logical Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators).

Comment: More accurately, if `$(el).data('start')` is "falsy" (that is, undefined, null, 0, false, an empty string, or `NaN`), then `new Date()` is evaluated and assigned to `time`.  Strangely, empty lists and empty objects are not considered falsy.

Answer (score 1):

The way the operator || is evaluated is that if the first part is true-ish, it returned it. If the first part is false-ish, it returns the second. 
The above expressions is therefore equivalent to:

```
if ($(el).data('start')) {
  time = $(el).data('start');
} else {
  time = new Date();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It means `logical sum`. `var time =  $(el).data('start') || new Date();` if `$(el).data('start')` will have `undefined` or `false` value then `time` will have value from `new Date` function.

Comment: thanks @Denis. how is `logical sum` different from `or`?

Comment: For downvoters what is wrote wrong?

Comment: I downvoted because it has misinformation. ` if $(el).data('start') will have undefined or false`. Is wrong.

Comment: What is wrong? Yes it not full list. Better say as convertiable to false. It will executed if $(el).data('start') returns undefined? or false?

Comment: If that's better to say, then you should have said that. Even in that case it would be not be useful answer because there are answers right next to it that explain what that means and what values convert to false.

Comment: But it's not wrong. Your downvote just for fun.