# Javascript: false || undefined vs undefined || false

Tags: javascript, undefined, logical-operators

What is the explanation for behavior of the "||" operator (logical OR), when using it with `false` and `undefined` on both sides in JavaScript?

1)

```
> false || undefined
undefined
```

2)

```
> undefined || false
false
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the || operator do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/830618/what-does-the-operator-do)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The logical `OR` operator isn't commutative like `+`, `*`, etc. It returns the first expression which can be converted into `true`. (Source [Mozilla Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators))

1. In `false || undefined`, `false` can't be converted to `true` by definition (since it's the opposite), so it returns the second operand (`undefined`)
2. In `undefined || false`, `undefined` is a value, but considered as `false` in Javascript, so the logical operator evaluate the second operand and returns `false` (because both operands are false).

Comment: sorry, do you have a typo in your second statement or maybe I'm not getting and there is a situation where `undefined || false` returns `undefined`? (originally should return `false`)

Comment: yeah indeed. I have mixed my ideas when I was writing I guess. I've fixed this.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Logical Operators in Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators):

> Logical OR (||)
>
> expr1 || expr2
>
> Returns 'expr1' if it can be converted to true; otherwise, returns 'expr2.

1) in case `false || undefined`: `false`(expr1) can not be converted to `true`, so `undefined`(expr2) is returned

2) in case `undefined || false`: `undefined`(expr1) can not be converted to `true`, so
`false`(expr2) is returned

Answer (score 3):

This question is not related particularly to just `false` and `undefined` but, to any of the [Falsy Values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) in Javascript. Note that there are a total of six falsy values in Javascript:

- false.
- 0 (zero)
- '' or "" (an empty string)
- null
- undefined
- NaN

When you run the logical OR operation between two Falsy Values, say `<left value> || <right value>` in JS, it always returns the value on the right side of the OR operator. Reason being that the OR operator, as per its implementation in [ECMAScript Engines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ECMAScript_engines), in general returns the left value if it can be coerced to `true`. But, if the value on the left side of the operator cannot be coerced to true, the right value is always returned no matter what the value on the right is, instead of getting coerced as one might expect.