# What this code means ([1, 2, 3] || 0)[0]

Tags: javascript

[Closure(Script) implementation in JavaScript called "wisp"](https://github.com/Gozala/wisp) has this snippet:

```
(get [1 2 3] 1) ; => ([1, 2, 3] || 0)[0]
```

which means that the wisp code compiles to this in JavaScript:

```
([1, 2, 3] || 0)[0]
```

But why is `|| 0` part there?

Comment: You want to understand the syntax of it or the logic?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the || operator do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/830618/what-does-the-operator-do)

Comment: It's just how the translation from Wisp syntax into JavaScript works to prevent runtime exceptions. If the expression were `(get x 1)` and the value of `x` were `undefined`, that would be an error in JavaScript, but not in ClojureScript (Wisp).

Comment: I thought so. Then I can't explain it to you :) There's no purpose to `OR` a `[1,2,3]` array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is that instead of writing a literal array, you can send it a variable:

```
(get x 1) ;
```

So the `|| 0` is used in case `x` is `null` or `undefined`.

In JavaScript, `||` does not return a boolean, it returns the 1st value if it's "truthy" and the 2nd if the 1st is "falsy".

`0[0]` returns `undefined` just like `[][0]` does.  `0` is one less character than `[]`, so that's probably why they did `|| 0` instead of `|| []`.

Comment: `||, does not return a boolean, it returns the 1st value` this just knocked me out right now

Comment: Yeah, that's one of the weird things about JavaScript (here are the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators).  If you do `'abc' || 'xyz'`, you'll get `'abc'`.

Answer (score 2):

Normally it would be used to specify a default value if the first part is null/undefined/false.

For example, consider the following code:

```
var a = 1;
var b;

var x = a || 0;//if a is true use a, otherwise use 0
var y = b || 0;//if b is true use b, otherwise use 0
```

The value of `x` will be `1`, because `1` is a truthy value and therefore becomes the value that is used. whereas `y` will be `0` because the value of `b` is undefined (a falsey value) so the `0` is used instead.

In your example however it is pointless, as `[1, 2, 3]` will always be true. But if you was using a variable then is would be possible for the variable to not be assigned, so the default value would then apply.

[Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/MayfE/) that shows how different types would apply

[Here is more information on Truthy and Falsey vaues](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/truthy-falsey/)

Comment: It's pointless but apparently it's what the "wisp" gets compiled to, probably as a precaution

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that the `|| 0` does anything. The `||` operator checks for a null, undefined etc, and if found will return the right hand side of the expression.

In this example `[1, 2, 3]` is never null so `0` will never be returned.